# go run main.go changes go module to an older version

Tags: go, go-modules

I am using `github.com/go-chi/jwtauth v1.2.0`, however as soon as I run my `main.go` my `go.mod` changes the library version to `github.com/go-chi/jwtauth v4.0.3+incompatible` which is an older version and doesn't have the functionality that I need. I tried to change the version back manually in the `go.mod` file, and the library updates for me, however as soon as I run the command `go run main.go` it reverts back to the old version. Why could this be happening and how could i solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: In general you should not be using `go run` for this, especially with filename arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-mod=readonly` to ask Go tools not to touch your `go.mod`. In fact, this is the by default case in Go 1.16, so I recommend you upgrade.

[FWIW, version v4.0.3 sounds like a *newer* version than v1.2.0]

Comment: You mean I should add the -mod=readonly when i run `go run main.go` ? Because it still goes back to the old version. And yes I know the version naming is pretty strange, but v1.2.0 is the newest version :)

Comment: @Marius You should not use `go run` **at all**`. You should `go build -mod=readonly`.

Comment: @Marius: can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? The smallest `main.go` and `go.mod` that demonstrates the problem for you, along with your Go version

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the module author upgraded the module to officially support Go modules (i.e. `go mod`). To do this and to keep the same URL, they had to set the module version to `1.x`. As a consequence, `go mod` thinks that `4.x` is later than `1.x` when in fact it is not (it's reasonable to think a larger number is later).

Some module authors create a new version, such as `v5`, but this would change the URL that the module is fetched from. Some authors are OK with this, others not so much.

In Go 1.16, there is the ability to `retract` previous versions of the module - this is a mark in the `go.mod` file that tells go not to use that version. Some authors may do this instead.

Hopefully this explains the why, and how some module authors are changing. It doesn't quite fix your problem in this case, but the `-mod=readonly` works.

FWIW, the module author here has created `v5.x` now, so this problem won't exist for this particular module.

Answer (score -1):

`go mod tidy` ensures that the go.mod file matches the source code in the module. It adds any missing module requirements necessary to build the current module's packages and dependencies, and it removes requirements on modules that don't provide any relevant packages. It also adds any missing entries to go.sum and removes unnecessary entries.
[Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy)